# on what programming language is android os and its kernel written?

Tags: android, kernel

I just want to know on what programming language is ***android* operating** system and it **kernel** is written..

---

Comment: check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)

Comment: Android runs an ARM Linux kernel, which is written in ARM assembly and C. The UI and other parts of the is are written in Davlik Java.

Answer (score 24):

Android is built on top of Linux, and a large portion of it is written in C. There are swaths of code written in C++ though. Also, most of the application framework (the stuff you would call android, and almost everything you see on screen) is written in Java.